# is there a consistent behavior when we set visibility gone on relative layout when another view is set above the gone view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have a relative layout with two views:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

<view
android:id:""+@id/view1"
android:layout_above:"+@id/view2" />


<view
android:id:""+@id/view2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there consistent behavior when I set view2 Visibility to gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestand you correctly you can do this in 3 ways:

- in this case you should use `linearlayout` because it will always be above view2 even if its *GONE*;
- if you want to maintain view1 on top of view2 like putting view2 visibility to *invisible*;
- or align view1 to parent if view2 is gone with this in your xml set to true: android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing

Let me know if I can help you.

Edit:
when you put the view to GONE is like it doesn't exist so, view1 will be placed just like this line doesn't exists: android:layout_above:"+@id/view2"

Comment: my questions is in theory. I just want to know what will be the positioning in that case. not looking for workarounds.

Comment: @EladBenda when you put the view to GONE is like it doesn't exist so, view1 will be placed just like this line doesn't exists: `android:layout_above:"+@id/view2"`